# how to associate checkbox with text box, so that selected checkbox and corresponding value of text box gets updated in database

Tags: java, jquery, jsp, spring-mvc, jdbctemplate

I want to associate checkbox id(which is  dynamically created) with text box.

For Example : If 5 check boxes are appearing along with 5 text boxes, i want that the check box i select the corresponding value will get update in database.

Problem : if 5 check boxes are appearing on jsp page and if i select 2, 4 and 5th checkboxes, then corresponding text box values i.e. 2,4 and 5th value should be inserted in database.
But in my case checkboxes are inserted correctly but values are not inserting. it is inserting like for 2nd check box ---> it is selecting first textbox,
and for 4th checkbox ----> it is selecting 2nd textbox value and for 5th checkbox it is selecting -----> 3 textbox value.

I known that it is because of this code : Here Attribute List contains three selected checkBox but attribute value contains 5 elements. and it will pick only three.

```
List<Object[]> inputList = new ArrayList<Object[]>();
for (int i = 0; i < qualification.getAttributeList().length; i++) {
    Object[] tmp = {newCompanyId,qualification.getAttributeList()[i],qualification.getAttributeValue()[i]};
    inputList.add(tmp);
```

Can anyone please let me know ho to solve the issue. Please find the attached pics.
[image: Page for adding new attributes]
**Qualification Controller**

@RequestMapping(value = "/save", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView save(ModelAndView model, HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res,
        @ModelAttribute Qualification qualification, HttpSession session) throws AppException {

```
String userId = session.getAttribute("loggedInUserId").toString();
qualificationDAO.save(qualification, userId);

model.setViewName("qualification");
return model;
```

}

**Qualification.jsp**

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="tg" tagdir="/WEB-INF/tags"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://tiles.apache.org/tags-tiles" prefix="tiles"%>
<jsp:useBean id="pagedListHolder" scope="request" class="org.springframework.beans.support.PagedListHolder" />

<!-- Main Body Section Start -->
<main class="container padContnr">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <h1>Qualification Rules</h1>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="bg-ltgreen padding-10 margin-t-10" id="QualEdit">
    <form:form class="form-horizontal" action="save" modelAttribute="qualification" method="post" >

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12">


          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="label-bg col-xs-12">Company <span class="red">*</span></label>
            <div class="col-xs-12">
             <form:select id="company" class="form-control" path="company">
                <form:option value="Select" />
                <form:options items="${companyList}" itemValue="id" itemLabel="dropdownValue"/>
            </form:select>
            </div>
          </div>


          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="label-bg col-xs-12">Class <span class="red">*</span></label>
            <div class="col-xs-12">
             <form:select id="companyClass" class="form-control" path="companyClass" onchange="switchOption();">
                <form:option value="Select" />
                <form:options items="${classList}" itemValue="id" itemLabel="dropdownValue"/>
            </form:select>              
            </div>
          </div>

      </div>

         <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12">

<%--           <div class="form-group">
            <label class="label-bg col-xs-12">Status <span class="red">*</span></label>
            <div class="col-xs-12">
              <form:select class="form-control" path="status" >
                <form:option value="Select"></form:option>
                <form:options items="${statusList}" itemValue="id" itemLabel="dropdownValue" />
              </form:select>
            </div>
          </div> --%>



           <div class="form-group">
            <label class="label-bg col-xs-12">Rule <span class="red">*</span></label>
            <div class="col-xs-12">
              <form:input path="rule" class="form-control" type="text" />
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>

      </div>
     <div id="QualAtt"class="row margin-t-10">
        <div id="QualAtt1" class="col-md-6">

        <!-- table data -->
        </div> 
      </div> 


      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 margin-t-10">
         <!--  <button class="btn btn-primary btnSubmit" type="submit" id="QualSav">Save</button> -->
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btnSubmit">                                                                                                                                                                                  </button>
          <button class="btn btn-default btnCancel" type="button" id="QualCanl">Cancel</button>
        </div>
      </div>

    </form:form>
  </div>

</main>
```

**Qualification Model**

```
package com.hcl.ne.model;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

/**
 * @author diwakar_b
 *
 */

public class Qualification {

    private int id;
    private String company;
    private String companyClass;
    private String rule;
    private String lastModifiedOn;
    private String lastModifiedBy;
    private String status;
    private String[] attributeList;
    private String[] attributeValue;
    private int pagesize;
    private String ruleId;
    private String[] attributeListNames;
    private String[] attributeValueNames;
    private String classId;
    private String attributeId;
    private String attributeName;
    private String attributeValues;


    public String[] getAttributeValue() {
        return attributeValue;
    }
    public void setAttributeValue(String[] attributeValue) {
        this.attributeValue = attributeValue;
    }
    public String getAttributeValues() {
        return attributeValues;
    }
    public void setAttributeValues(String attributeValues) {
        this.attributeValues = attributeValues;
    }
    public String getAttributeName() {
        return attributeName;
    }
    public void setAttributeName(String attributeName) {
        this.attributeName = attributeName;
    }

    public String getAttributeId() {
        return attributeId;
    }
    public void setAttributeId(String attributeId) {
        this.attributeId = attributeId;
    }
    public String[] getAttributeList() {
        return attributeList;
    }
    public void setAttributeList(String[] attributeList) {
        this.attributeList = attributeList;
    }
    public String getCompany() {
        return company;
    }
    public void setCompany(String company) {
        this.company = company;
    }
    public String getCompanyClass() {
        return companyClass;
    }
    public void setCompanyClass(String companyClass) {
        this.companyClass = companyClass;
    }
    public String getRule() {
        return rule;
    }
    public void setRule(String rule) {
        this.rule = rule;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }
    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }
    public String getLastModifiedOn() {
        return lastModifiedOn;
    }
    public void setLastModifiedOn(String lastModifiedOn) {
        this.lastModifiedOn = lastModifiedOn;
    }
    public String getLastModifiedBy() {
        return lastModifiedBy;
    }
    public void setLastModifiedBy(String lastModifiedBy) {
        this.lastModifiedBy = lastModifiedBy;
    }

    public int getPagesize() {
        return pagesize;
    }
    public void setPagesize(int pagesize) {
        this.pagesize = pagesize;
    }
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getRuleId() {
        return ruleId;
    }
    public void setRuleId(String ruleId) {
        this.ruleId = ruleId;
    }

    public String[] getAttributeListNames() {
        return attributeListNames;
    }
    public void setAttributeListNames(String[] attributeListNames) {
        this.attributeListNames = attributeListNames;
    }
    public String[] getAttributeValueNames() {
        return attributeValueNames;
    }
    public void setAttributeValueNames(String[] attributeValueNames) {
        this.attributeValueNames = attributeValueNames;
    }
    public String getClassId() {
        return classId;
    }
    public void setClassId(String classId) {
        this.classId = classId;
    }


}
```

**PLugin.js**

```
$('#QualSav, #QualCanl').on('click', function() {
    $("#QualEdit").hide();
    $("#QualRules").hide();
    $("#QualSerch").show();
}); 

// Qualification -- Edit

$('#EditBtnQualification').on('click', function() {
    var ruleId=$('table.trClick tbody tr.trActive td:first').html();
       $('#ruleId').val(ruleId);
       document.qualificationEditForm.submit();
});


function switchOption() {
    var  selectedValue= $("#companyClass").val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "getClass",
        data:'classId='+selectedValue,
        success: function(data){

            var tablebody = $('<tbody>');
            var tablerow = "";
            $(data.resultMenuForLocation).each(function(index){
                tablerow = $('<tr>')
                    .append($('<td>').append($('<input>').attr({type :'checkbox'}).attr('class','checkBoxSize').attr({value : ''+$(this)[0].id}).attr('id','attributeList').attr('name','attributeList')))
                    .append($('<td>').append($(this)[0].dropdownValue+''))
                    .append($('<td>').append($('<input>').attr({type :'text'}).attr('class','form-control').attr('id','attributeValue').attr('name','attributeValue')))
                $(tablebody).append(tablerow);
            });
            $('<table>')
            .attr('id','master_table')
            .attr('class','myAttr f-size-16')
            .html('<thead><tr><th>&nbsp;</th><th>Attribute</th><th>Value</th></tr></thead>')
            .append(tablebody)
            .appendTo('div#QualAtt1');

        }

});

};
```

Comment: by implementing a simple 'if' statement. if isChecked, upload field (and all that). this you should be able to do years before considering going to use a db

Comment: @Stultuske thanks for your response but in my code my checkbox is already mapped to model i.e. attributeList[] so that checkbox id i am getting but my question is how to associate the corresponding text box with checkbox so the selected check box and only corresponding text box get saved in my db.

Comment: diwakar: yes, I understand, and that is exactly what I told you how to do.

Comment: sorry @Stultuske but i am not getting it, if i checked that check box is true or not in if loop than inside  that body how will i come to know that which check box id is associated with textbox. because value will be inserted correctly if i select all 5 checkbox  and provide correspond text. but when i select some checkbox for example 2,3,5 (small snippet code i have provided in starting of question) the value of textbox it is selecting for 0,1,2 textbox which is  incorect.  can you please explain with some example.

Comment: you write code that handles that. if ( checkbox1.isChecked()) { updateText1();} or something similar

Comment: my attributeList array contains 3 checked attList i.e. RAM, C, D and attributeValue[] contains 5 elements as you can see in attached pic. while iterating the loop corresponding value is wrong. I am setting these values into model i.e. attributeList[] and attributeValue[].from plugin.js as in spring mvc only checked values set into model and also the all textbox vaues set into model array. Is there any way to **bind the attributeList to corresponding attributeValue** in **plugin.js**  itself so that while fetching i will get the right values.

Comment: Any Possible Solutions..?

Comment: Any Possible Solutions..?